# 3rd party plugin licencing, when launching on the google play store

Tags: mit-license, apache-license, release

I have created an app using Cordova, that I want to release on the Google play store. My app uses other peoples plugins that have a variety of licences, including Apache licence and MIT. I believe that I need to reference their work at some point. how do you recommend I do this? eg in an 'about' popup in app? or does it need to be somewhere specific?

Also, I do not understand how to reference their material. Do I list all the names of people I have referenced? and copy the copyright for each plugin used?

Thanks for any help, or any examples of how people have referenced would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Through looking at other applications, I have found most have a licence page or tab built into the application, where they list all third party software used, with their original licence pasted.

They usually add their own licence above these

See: Snapchat (android app) licence button built into the app.